# Table or view not found: SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am attempting to find the max value from SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS using `SELECT MAX(values) FROM SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS` in using `glue_context.sql` but I received the error  Table or view not found: SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS.

In this glue script, I can read data from a specific data catalogue but I dont know how to read system views and table from glue. Please help?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what you were trying to do? Where is `glue_context.sql` and how did you create the schema?

Comment: sorry I cant share the full code but glue_context works as I can read data from other catalogue into dynamicFrame....its only this one script where it threw an error I dont recognise.